# TestMethod do not support getContent call

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout

I have a requirement to send a specific report as an attachment on schedule basis.

So, i have created a schedule class with future annotation to send.But now when i'm trying to setup apex class I'm getting below error.

> Error Message Methods defined as TestMethod do not support getContent
>   call

Apex class:

```
global class CallSubscriptionReportScheduler {
@future(callout=true)
    public static void SentSubscriptionData()
    {
        Id userdetail=[Select id from user where email='xyz@gmail.com'].id;
        OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'info@xyz.com' Limit 1];
        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O6F00000CGpHH?csv=1');
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attachment.setFileName('Data_Report.csv');
        attachment.setBody(report.getContent());
        attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
        message.setSubject('Data');
        message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');
        message.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
        message.setReplyTo('sfdcadmin@xyz.com');
        message.setTargetObjectId(userdetail);
        message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } ); 
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class TestWeeklySubscriptionData {
    public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 1 ? * MON';
    static testmethod void testsubscription() {        
            Test.startTest();
            WeeklySubscriptionData uca = new WeeklySubscriptionData();
            String jobId = System.schedule('ScheduledApexTest',CRON_EXP,new WeeklySubscriptionData());
            Test.stopTest();
            // after the testing stops, assert records were updated properly
            //System.assertEquals(6, [select count() from Lead where Lead_Type__c='Insurance' AND RecordTypeId ='0126F0000016MZP']);
    }
}
```

Could someone help me.

Comment: Best you include the error message.

Comment: I have updated my question @KeithC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found no way to handle this other than using the last resort [Test.isRunningTest](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205831):

```
PageReference pr = ...;

Blob pdf = !Test.isRunningTest() ? pr.getContentAsPdf() : Blob.valueOf('Fake content');
```

or in your class:

```
attachment.setBody(!Test.isRunningTest() ? report.getContent() : Blob.valueOf('Fake content'));
```

Comment: Hey sorry could you please me know how to setup this in my test class. i don't have any idea about this

Comment: Added @Pavantej.

Comment: Works likes a charm. But i have a doubt can we use mockclass instead of this?

Comment: @Pavantej Mocking for this isn't possible AFAIK. Web service callouts should use mocking not this technique.